# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: got asked about an unknown fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager and 3 fragment .
my app work good with 2 of them but when i add the third fragment its return this error :

```
12-17 14:11:30.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: got asked about an unknown fragment
```

a part of my code is like this :

```
if (position == 0) {
      if (mContactList == null)
          mContactList = new ContactListFragment();
                return mContactList;
} else if (position == 1) {
      if (mContact == null)
          mContact= new ContactFragment(); // my third fragment  
          return mContact ;
} else {
      int positionMod = position - 2;
      mCursor.moveToPosition(positionMod);
      long contactChatId = mCursor.getLong(ChatView.CONTACT_ID_COLUMN);
      String contactName = mCursor.getString(ChatView.USERNAME_COLUMN);
      long providerId = mCursor.getLong(ChatView.PROVIDER_COLUMN);
      return ChatViewFragment.newInstance(contactChatId, contactName, providerId);
}
```

Comment: Plz share the complete code

Comment: my code is a bit complex and too long ; :-/

Comment: I m not understaing what u have done ?

Comment: i just want to know why and when this error happening ! sorry if my english is poor

Comment: I can't say about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are trying to refer other fragments from your current fragment. 
Try to set setOffscreenPageLimit to 2. As stated in the docs :

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Use this code :

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.historypager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```